# How can I prove that one less than a power of ten is a multiple of $9$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Please forgive me; I'm not very good at math.

I'm trying to prove this:

if $b$ is a positive integer, then $10^b - 1 = 9k$.

Comment: Cast out nines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work by induction.

Base case, $n=1: 10^1-1=9=9\cdot 1$

Then assume true for $n=k$: $$10^k-1=9\lambda$$
It follows that $$90\lambda=10^{k+1}-10\implies10^{k+1}-1=90\lambda+9=9(10\lambda+1)$$
that is, $9| 10^k-1 \implies 9|10^{k+1}-1$ and so it is true for all $n\in \Bbb N$

Answer (score 7):

$10^b-1=(10-1)(10^{b-1}+10^{b-2}+10^{b-3}+\cdots+10^2+10+1)$

Answer (score 2):

The binomial theorem (as per @Arturo's comment):  $10^b=(1+9)^b=1^b+\binom b1\cdot9\cdot1^{b-1}+\binom b2\cdot9^2\cdot1^{b-2}+\dots+9^b\cong1\bmod9$.